# converting to local time from timezone offset using moment.js

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, momentjs

I m having a datetime with timezone offset in a DOM. It looks like -

```
<div id="some">2014-09-26 23:57:02 +0530</div>
```

Now In chrome I able to convert it to local browser's time using the code below with moment.js.

In FF it complains invalid time and IE throws the time as it is. The example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmdxsqa7/).

The code -

```
 jQuery.fn.extend({
    convertTime: function(format) {
     return this.each(function(i, e) {
         var txt = $(e).html() ;
         try {
            $(e).html(  moment(txt).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
         } catch(err) {console.log (err.message);$(e).html(txt);}
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass a format string to moment so it won't fall back to the brower's date parser.

```
moment(txt,'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss ZZ').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Alternatively, pass the data in a format that moment recognizes [as listed here](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/).  In your case, simply removing the space between the time and the offset would work.

```
var txt = '2014-09-26 23:57:02+0530';
moment(txt).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')
```

Comment: sorry it works in IE. Some other problem with my code.